# Перегрузка оператора вывода <<

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Для опытов со структурами данных написал такую структуру:

```
typedef struct complex{
    double real;
    double imaginary;
public:
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, complex &c){
        os << "(" << c.real << ", " << c.imaginary << ")";
        return os;
    }
}complex;
```

При компиляции выдается сообщение о том, что оператор должен принимать единственный аргумент. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что я здесь использую структуру вместо класса (примеров с классами и в интернете много). Но класс мне кажется слишком тяжелым для комплексного числа, классы нужны для абстрагирования целых сущностей со сложным строением и действиями, а здесь и делать-то нечего. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определенный вами оператор как функция член класса имеет неявный параметр - указатель на экземпляр класса, то есть `this`.

В результате он имеет, фактически три параметра вместо двух, как полагается для этого бинарного оператора.

Либо объявите функцию со спецификатором `friend`. Либо вынесите определение (и, соответственно, объявление) функции за пределы класса. То есть сделайте ее не функцией - членом класса.

Имейте в виду, что так как вы используете ключевое слово `struct` в объявлении класса, то его члены real и imaginary имеют по умолчанию класс доступа `public`

Итак, либо напишите

```
struct complex{
//private:
    double real;
    double imaginary;
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const complex &c){
        os << "(" << c.real << ", " << c.imaginary << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
```

Либо

```
typedef struct complex{
    double real;
    double imaginary;
}complex;

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const complex &c){
    os << "(" << c.real << ", " << c.imaginary << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Про передачу скрытого параметра this в питоне я читал, а про такое же в C++ не слышал. Почему тогда перегрузка операторов сравнения не приводит к таким ошибкам?

Comment: @typemoon  Для оператора сравнения  должна возникнуть точно такая же ошибка компиляции.